# Search for and kill PIDs, one at a time

Tags: batch-file, taskkill

I have the following command that works pretty well:

```
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| grep :7010') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P /F
```

The issue is, if the same port is found multiple times with the same PID, my script returns `errno 1` because the attempts to kill the PID after the first have failed.

Is there a way to modify the above so that it only attempts to kill the PID once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might work for you:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| grep :7010') DO (
    IF NOT DEFINED PID.%%P (
        TASKKILL.exe /PID %%P /F
        SET "PID.%%P=7"
    )
)
```

Comment: This worked great - did you set PID.P to 7 arbitrarily? Also, can you elaborate on the need for disableDelayedExpansion?

Comment: `7` is _The Magical Batch Number_; but you can replace it :) `disableDelayedExpansion`: you can set the delayed expansion status in the registry or on the command line. I use this always to get a defined start environment. It is not necessary in this case.